# How to pass in a string as a single value and not a split value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function called onClick of a div that calls a dispatch function, and passes in the target value into it (i.e `e.target.value`). The value being passed in, is being stored in an array.

However, I noticed something weird going on. In the array the value is being passed into, the first value is stored wrongly.

For instance if I pass in `'hello'`, in the array, it is stored as `['h','e','l','l','o']`. And this only happens with the first value that is passed in, the rest are stored properly.

This is my function, the one called onClick;

```
const handleSelectedFilters = (e: any) => {
  dispatch(
    actions.storeData({
      name: data.name,
      values: e.target.value,
    }),
  );
}
```

And this is the action in my reducer file;

```
export interface DataState {
  name: string,
  values: Array<string>,
}

export interface FilterState {
  storedData: DataState[];
}

applyData: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<DataState>,
    ) => {
        state.storedData.push({
          name: action.payload.name,
          values: [...action.payload.values],
        });
    },
```

Please any help will be appreciated as I am really stuck. What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing your `values` as `values: [...action.payload.values]`

If you do:

```
var text: String = "hello":
console.log([...text]);
```

You will see how the spread operator placed inside the array will split your string into an array.

#### Solution

Just save it as `values: action.payload.values`

Comment: That actually worked to fix the issue but the reason I did it that way was to spread whatever value into the array, now it doesn't do that. It just takes the first value and stores it. Do you have any idea how I can work around that?

Comment: You can pass [values: e.target.value] as values in your action. I mean, you have to make sure you always pass an array, you can't pass sometimes a string and sometimes an array :)